# California: A mechanic serviced Bob's car, has it in his shop, and verbally agreed to buy it from him. Is Bob liable for accidents before it's sold?

Tags: california, liability, driving, car-title, accident-insurance

### TL;DR

Bob took his car in to a mechanic (M). After M worked on it, Bob decided to sell it to him. It's currently in his shop but it'll take Bob over two weeks to sign over the title.

In the meantime, **if he or one of his employees gets in an accident in his car, will Bob be legally and financially responsible?** If so, how does Bob eliminate or reduce that risk to himself?

---

### Additional Context

Bob has a really old car and the check engine light was on. He took it to a mechanic and quoted Bob $2500 for the original repairs: the engine was leaking all over the place, including the oil pan and some broken ignition coils. The car isn't worth that much, but it would last for years after this repair, so it seemed worth it anyway.

Once Bob gave him the go-ahead to work on that, he found $2k in more issues: the radiator is cracked, the water pump is broken, and so is the engine mount.

At that point, Bob decided it wasn't worth the investment. Bob proposed to him that Bob would pay for the work he's done up to that point (M *said* it was the $2500) and sell the car to him for $2000. Therefore, Bob would end up owing him $500 total.

Both agreed to this, but here's the tricky part: Bob couldn't find his title. Bob also recently changed his address and informed the DMV of that yesterday. According to their website, Bob has two wait two weeks after an address change before Bob can start the process of getting a replacement title then sign it over.

At the moment, the car is in his possession but the title and insurance is in his name. Here's his main concern: **if he or one of his employees gets in an accident before the title change, will Bob be legally and financially responsible?** If so, how does Bob eliminate or reduce that risk to himself?

Here's the "paper trail," so to speak:

Bob took the car in and signed some paperwork saying he could work on the car. (Come to think of it, he didn't even give Bob a copy!) Bob's been texting him every step of the way to tell him he approves of the fixes he's going to make and saying he wants to sell the car.

But this is all one sided: Bob's been texting M about approving things, but M hasn't been texting Bob about anything; the rest of the details have been over the phone -- including his agreement to buy it from Bob. Bob doesn't even have an itemized list of the amount of work he's put in before the sales agreement (though Bob said he would need to see it before Bob signed over the title).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re looking for something called the “permissive driver law.” I’ll include a link to the [full text](http://www.christian-attorney.net/permissive_use_law_california.html), but here’s a summary:

You still own the car, and the insurance is still in your name. If the mechanic takes your car out for a drive and gets in an accident, the damages will fall upon you and your insurance provider—your insurance would be deemed the “primary coverage” since you own the vehicle. The exception is personal injury—if the mechanic himself gets injured, his insurance is likely liable for that expense.*

This doesn’t have to be the case, though. You don’t *have* to make the mechanic a permissive driver. If you don’t trust him, or just don’t want the liability, tell him so **in writing**. Or, you could set limits on the usage, like permitting him to drive around town but not on the interstate. As long as these conditions are in writing, they shield you from all liability related to operation of the car. In fact, it would be a crime for the mechanic to violate these conditions.

You could also potentially be liable through something called “negligent entrustment,” which is basically when you lend your car to someone who should not be driving (i.e. they are too young, have a suspended license, etc.). Based on your question, this doesn’t seem to apply.

*This is generally true, but check your specific policy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for my naïveté, but does an e-mail count as "in writing"? Does a text message count?

Comment: Yep those both work fine. Just make sure there’s a clear record of when you sent it, who sent it, and whether he received it.

Comment: If they don't reply to the text or the email, how do I record whether they received it?

Comment: Strictly speaking, I suppose you don’t have to record whether they received it. But if they do respond, you should definitely record that as proof that they got it—this will make things much easier in the unfortunate event that you need to go to court. Essentially, just keep records of as much as you can.

Comment: @DanielKaplan "Many cases have found service of process by email to be reasonably calculated to provide actual notice when the test email is not returned as undeliverable or bounced back." (_Fed. Trade Comm'n v. Cottelli_, No. 20-15717, 3 (9th Cir. Mar. 30, 2021) 

**Actual notice is not sufficient for proper service of process**, but the requirement merely of written notice is not the same as the requirement of providing service of process on a party.

Comment: @JackEdwards would the "permissive driver law" be applicable to a manufacturer for in case of returning a vehicle merely for the purposes of warranty service or repairs?

Comment: @JackEdwards This is disgusting! 
"Every owner of a motor vehicle is liable and responsible for death or injury to person or property resulting from a negligent or wrongful act or omission in the operation of the motor vehicle, in **the business of the owner** or otherwise, by any person using or operating the same with the permission, express or implied, of the owner." The only enumerated example relates to when the permission is given in "the business of the owner" everything else is left to the imagination of the courts. The only thing apparently that they read out of it: Bigco.

Comment: @kisspuska I'm sorry, but I'm not able to follow. Are you in agreement or disagreement with what Jack has said?

Comment: @DanielKaplan I have been trying to find a single case when a "permissive driver law" or Veh. Code §17510 kicked in during a service appointment with a mechanic, the dealership or a repair facility maintained by the manufacturer, and found none where they pushed liability back onto the owner (or their insurance). Maybe that could be construed from the plain meaning of the words, but such construction would probably result in the absurd consequence that is keeping me up at 2:30 AM. I can only hope Jack is wrong. What he suggests is an absolutely outrageous proposition taking a major piss.

Comment: @kisspuska There is certainly a difference between a standard service appointment and what is happening here. To my knowledge, if I bring my car in for an oil change and the mechanic crashes it into the garage, I’m not responsible at all (this is probably covered in the contract between myself and the service provider). However, I believe that the relationship between Mr. Kaplan and his mechanic now falls outside of the service contract and has evolved into an automobile sale, in which case permissive driver laws are certainly in effect.

Comment: For example, if I’m selling a used car and someone takes it for a test drive and crashes, my insurance is (probably) liable. Regardless of what terms were in the service agreement between Mr. Kaplan and his mechanic, I see no reason the same legal argument can’t be applied here.

Comment: @JackEdwards Ah, now I understand. Although, there is no contract between them only a verbal agreement (this should not limit the tacit permission for the purposes of §17150, but it does have other statutory limitations (no good faith duty, etc.)

Comment: @DanielKaplan Personally, I wouldn't proceed until I had received an affirmative response (by email) to my email. There's rarely if ever reason to put oneself in a position where you may have to argue whether or not the other party had seen and agreed to it.